# Onmouseover/onmouseout working on firefox,chrome,safari But not on IE (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I am using a javascript function  to change image on mouseover and onmouserout in asp.net3.5, its working perfectly for firefox, chrome and safari but when i test same flyout on IE then onmouseover/onmouseout image does not change. Please help and guide me in this way.....

I am waiting for your response.

Regards

Arshad

Comment: thats very very nice that you are waiting, as we are waiting for some indication that you tried something, **anything**

Comment: Can you post your existing code so we can try to understand your problem better?

Comment: ok i will upload some code about this, that i have tried yet.....

Comment: <a href="<%=strAppRootPath %>Super-Users/Carriers/CarrierProfile.aspx?DispDiv=TERMINALPOIT&CarrierID=3551">
                                                    <img onmouseover="SelectImage(this,'<%=strAppRootPath %>Images/setupOn.png','k');"
                                                        onmouseout="SelectImage(this,'<%=strAppRootPath %>Images/setupOff.png','o');"
                                                        src="<%=strAppRootPath %>Images/setupOff.png" style="border: none;"   />
                                                </a>

Comment: above is my code snippet that is working fine on other browsers except IE...

Comment: put that into your question please...

Comment: I can only provide you my vague answer to your question with a posted link, but next time, please post as much C#, Javascript, and ASP.net code as you can. The more details you provide, the better I can help you fix what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onMouseLeave` event for IE. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer might be more of a comment, but not knowing what SelectImage(this,...,'k' or 'o') is and that why you'll need that kind of function, I can only provide you a vague answer because you did not provide as much details as you can, such as your C# and Javascript code.

http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=110

Comment: selectimage() is a javascript function where img src is to be changed on mouseover/onmouseout..

Comment: actually i am using obout easymenu on an inline page... there on mouseover/onmouseout image is not been changed.